# (JavaFX WebEngine) JavaScript-to-Java Calls Work Inconsistently

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, javafx, jsobject

Good day,

I am having issues with my app's custom minimize and close buttons working inconsistently. I would like to fix this before advancing this project and making it more complicated.

---

## Background

The app is an undecorated JavaFX stage that contains a `WebView` that loads a JSP hosted by an embedded Tomcat server. The **minimize** and **close** buttons are HTML within the JSP and have `onclick` listeners that call Java methods to minimize and close the app via a JavaScript-to-Java interface class, `AppHandle`, and a delegate-class, `AppUtility`.

---

## Issue

The buttons work, but work inconsistently. Also, whenever the buttons do fail at random, they fail together.

E.g.

- Launch app, the buttons don't work.
- Launch app, buttons work. Minimize the app, maximize the app - now buttons don't work.
- Launch app, buttons work. Minimize and maximize the app once, buttons still work. Do it once or twice more - now buttons don't work.
- etc.

---

## Code

**JavaFX Components**

```
Stage
|  
\-- StackPane
   |  
   \-- Browser (contains the WebView/WebEngine)
```

The `Browser` class extends `Region` and houses the `WebView` and its `WebEngine`. This is where the `AppHandle` class is bound to the "`app`" label within the JSP.

```java
public Browser(String page, final AppUtility utility) {
  browser.setFontSmoothingType(FontSmoothingType.GRAY);
  browser.setContextMenuEnabled(false);

  webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
    .addListener(
      new ChangeListener<State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, 
            State oldState, State newState) { 
          if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
            JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
            win.setMember("app", new AppHandle(utility));
          }
        }
      }
    );
  webEngine.load(page);
  getChildren().add(browser);
}
```

Here is the relevant portion of the JSP where the buttons call the `AppHandler` methods `onclick`.

```
<div class="container-app">
  <div class="text-title">myApp</div>

  <div class="icon utility minimize" onclick="app.hide()">
    <i class="fa fa-window-minimize" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="icon utility close" onclick="app.exit()">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the `AppHandle` class, its methods are called from the `onclick` events in the JSP. If I put `print` statements in the `exit()` and `hide()` classes, they will not execute when the buttons fail. Which leads me to believe something is failing with the `JSObject`.

```java
public class AppHandle {
  private AppUtility utility;

  public AppHandle(AppUtility utility) {
    this.utility = utility;
  }

  public void exit() {
    utility.exit();
  }

  public void hide() {
    utility.hide();
  }
}
```

The `AppUtility` methods act on the JavaFX `Stage` to hide and close the JavaFX `Application`. I originally thought something might be wrong with my `show/hide/inconified` logic, but this code doesn't even get executed when the buttons fail.

```java
public void exit() {
  if (SystemTray.isSupported())
    SystemTray.getSystemTray().remove(app.getTrayIcon());
  Platform.exit();
  System.exit(0);
}

public void hide() {        
  if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
    try {
      SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(app.getTrayIcon());
      displayIconDialogue();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  app.getWindow().setIconified(true);
  app.getWindow().hide();
}

public void show() {
  if (SystemTray.isSupported())
    SystemTray.getSystemTray().remove(app.getTrayIcon());
  app.getWindow().setIconified(false);
  app.getWindow().show();
}
```

---

## Questions

1. How can I assess the "health" of my JSObject during run-time to see if it is the culprit?
2. Is there anything here that would explicitly break the connection between the JSP and the `AppHandle` on launch? On `minimize`? On `show`?

This would be easier if it just didn't work at all, I'm not sure where the inconsistency is coming from.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bah, I solved it. Let this be a lesson to me to search for questions better.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46744432/1038988) clued me in to the problem.

I am creating the `AppHandle` locally within the `JSObject`. I guess at some point the local `AppHandle` gets dereferenced and with it goes my JSP-to-Java connection.

I now make the `AppHandle` in the `AppClient` and pass it into the `Browser`. That way the app maintains a reference to the handle. The `Browser` constructor was changed to the following:

```java
public Browser(String page, AppHandle handle) {
  browser.setFontSmoothingType(FontSmoothingType.GRAY);
  browser.setContextMenuEnabled(false);

  webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
    .addListener(
      new ChangeListener<State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, 
            State oldState, State newState) { 
          if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
            JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
            win.setMember("app", handle);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  webEngine.load(page);
  getChildren().add(browser);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved my problem too. I wonder if gets garbage collected or something when declared anonymously. The nasty thing, creating it locally is proposed by the official documentation. 